# jquery Rest APi json

Tags: jquery, json, rest, api

I have this code in jquery 3.2.1.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://xxx:8080/v1/objects/Kunde?query=query=%7B%22queryString%22%3A%22query%20Name1%20%3D%20%5C%22*%5C%22%3B%22%7D",
    type: "GET",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        "appkey": "123", 
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", 
        "Authorization":"Basic VGVzdDo1NmQ2Njg3YmEyMGM5YzFjN2Q1MGUyOGY4NTI0MTA3Yg==", 
        "sessionId": sessionID
    },    
    cache: false,
    success: function (jo) {
        var Kunde = jo.data;
        $("#daises").html(Kunde);
    }
});
```

If i try the request by RestClient I get this "Answer" in Json.

```
{
    "status": {
        "internalStatus": "0",
        "statusMessage": "ok"
    },
    "data": {
        "~Count": 108,
        "~Elements": [
            {
                "~ClassName": "Vorgang",
                "~ObjectID": "7GCJ",
                "~StoreTime": "20161104T125531"
            },
            {
                "~ClassName": "Vorgang",
                "~ObjectID": "7PJ6",
                "~StoreTime": "20161220T164103"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I need is `~ObjectID` but I can´t figure out how to get this Objects. I tried different ways but I got only zero entries.

Can anybody assist me?

@antpaw
So, what I tried is this

```
     $.ajax (
  {

                   url: "http://xx:8080/v1/objects/Kunde?query=query=%7B%22queryString%22%3A%22query%20Name1%20%3D%20%5C%22*%5C%22%3B%22%7D",
                   type: "GET",
                   crossDomain: true,
                   dataType : "json",
                   headers : {"appkey" : "123" , 
                   "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                   "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*", 
                   "Authorization":"Basic VGVzdDo1NmQ2Njg3YmEyMGM5YzFjN2Q1MGUyOGY4NTI0MTA3Yg==", 
                   "sessionId": sessionID },

                   cache: false,
                   success: function (jo) {
                   var Kunde = jo.data["~Elements"].forEach(function(element){
  element["~ObjectID"]
});
                   $("#daises").html(Kunde);
                   }
                   })
}
             })
```

But I still get zero Objects. could this be a problen on another point? On Firefox console there are zero Elements also. here the encoded URL `{"queryString":"query Nummer = \"*\";"}`

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

ObjectID is stored inside an Array

```
jo.data["~Elements"][0]["~ObjectID"] // get objectId of first item
jo.data["~Elements"].forEach(function(element){
  element["~ObjectId"]
}) // iterate items
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

You can also access `json properties using index syntax`

Expecting you have assigned your JSON response to `value`

```
$.each( value.data["~Elements"], function( key, value ) {
  console.log(value["~ObjectID"]);
});
```

Comment: Its my pleasure. Make sure to accept answer so that it helps others

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this,

```
success: function (jo) {
    var Kunde = jo.data;
    var elements = Kunde.~Elements;
    var arrayOfObjectID = [];
    $.each(elements, function (i,v){
         arrayOfObjectID[i] = v.~ObjectID;
    });
//arrayOfObjectID should contain all the ObjectID values that you have in your json
    $("#daises").html(arrayOfObjectID);
}
```